# How to do reverse animation in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

So for the following code, I have a circular notification that animates, opening up left and displaying information and a profile image. I would like to be able to reverse the animation back by having the circle go forward covering up the info and fading out (which I already have inputed).  However, I'm not sure how to implement this. I've tried a couple of ways like switching the animation around but it doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

You can click the "CLOSE ME" button to close the notification and the "OPEN ME" to open it as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function(e) {
    $(".pgn-wrapper").fadeIn(250);
  });

  $(".close").click(function(e) {
    $(".pgn-wrapper").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Circle Animation
------------------------------------
*/
.pgn-circle .alert {
  border-radius: 300px;
  animation: fadeInCircle 0.3s ease forwards,
    resizeCircle 0.3s 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.25, 0.4, 1.6) forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInCircle 0.3s ease forwards,
    resizeCircle 0.3s 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.25, 0.4, 1.6) forwards;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px 55px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  position: relative;
}

.pgn-wrapper[data-position$='-right'] .pgn-circle .alert {
  float: right;
}

.pgn-wrapper[data-position$='-left'] .pgn-circle .alert {
  float: left;
}

.pgn-circle .alert > div > div.pgn-thumbnail > div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

.pgn-circle .alert > div > div.pgn-thumbnail > div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pgn-circle .alert > div > div.pgn-message > div {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 47px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  animation: fadeIn .3s .5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .3s .5s ease forwards;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.pgn-circle .alert > div > div.pgn-message > div p:only-child {
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.pgn-circle .alert .close {
  margin-top: -12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn .3s .5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .3s .5s ease forwards;
}

.pgn-circle .alert p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.pgn-circle .alert > div {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.pgn-circle .alert > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@keyframes fadeInCircle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 60px;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 60px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInCircle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 60px;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 60px;
  }
}

@keyframes resizeCircle {
  0% {
    width: 60px;
  }

  100% {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes resizeCircle {
  0% {
    width: 60px;
  }

  100% {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.close:target {
  animation: resizeCircle2 1s all;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes resizeCircle2 {
  0% {
    width: 300px;
  }

  100% {
    width: 60px;
  }
}



/* Headings 
------------------------------------
*/
p {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-style: normal;
  white-space: normal;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
/* Alert 
------------------------------------
*/
.alert {
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 9px 19px 9px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.alert-danger, .alert-error {
  background-color: #c42827;
  color: white;
  border-color: #933432;
}

.alert-danger .close, .alert-error .close {
  background-position: -95px -10px !important;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
Notifications
--------------------------------------------------
*/

.pgn-wrapper[data-position='top'] {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.pgn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pgn .alert {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div class="pgn-wrapper" data-position="top-right">
  <div class="pgn push-on-sidebar-open pgn-circle">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <div>
        <div class="pgn-thumbnail">
          <div>
            <img width="40" height="40" style="display: inline-block;" src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pgn-message">
          <div>
            <p class="bold" style="color:white">John Doe</p>
            <p>Logging out in <b>60</b> second(s).</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="open" href="#">OPEN ME</a>
<a class="close" href="#">CLOSE ME</a>

<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got a ton of code and I didn't parse through all of it, but I can say that when you have an animation like this:

```
@keyframes resizeCircle {
    0% {
        width: 60px;
    }

    100% {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

You are indicating where the width should start and end so to reverse that, you'd want to either ensure that this animation is tied to a temporary state, like a hover with a selector like this:

```
element:hover {
  animation:resizeCircle 1s all;
}
```

Then, the animation would only apply when the element is being hovered and when it isn't the element will animate back to its original state.

Or, you could set up a separate animation that specifies the reverse property values:

```
@keyframes resizeCircle2 {
    0% {
        width: 300px;
    }

    100% {
        width: 60px;
    }
}
```

and apply that to a "trigger" selector, such as:

```
element:target {
  animation:resizeCircle2 1s all;
}
```

Which would (in this case) apply the reverse animation when the element is the target of a click.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
<div class="expandable"></div>

div.expandable {
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

div.expandable:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

You can give that a run here: https://plnkr.co/edit/wa5Ny6vmluJv6xeDs7qt?p=preview